# color switcher in mootools OR jquery

Tags: jquery, mootools

this is my simple javascript function to switch colors and it works fine , but as far as i need to enable jquery or mootools in my website then its better to have this function modernized

```
function changeThemeColor(color)
{
    switch(color)
    {
        case "style1":
        default:
            document.getElementById('CSSfile').href = 'css/style1.css';
            setCookie('ThemeColor','style1',7);
            break;
        case "style2":
            document.getElementById('CSSfile').href = 'css/style2.css';
            setCookie('ThemeColor','style6',7);
            break;
    }
}
```

i know this maybe a huge quest but i really need to convert this code either into jquery or mootools

Comment: What do you mean by modernized?

Comment: hey patrick , i just need to know how to write these functions in mootools or jquery and base my project codes on these frameworks

Comment: Unless there are cross-browser issues with your code, or you just need to reduce the characters in the a very long bit of code, I'm not sure why you would want to slow it down with a library.

Comment: yeah you are right but i just need these examples for furture codes that are based on jquery or mootools

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. Do you mean this isn't the actual code you need converted? Just because you're using jQuery/MooTools in a project, doesn't mean that all of your javascript needs to use them. Converting to a library slows down your code. Sorry if I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code works, why slow it down be converting it to library code that will just convert it back to what you have?

If this is actually what your code looks like, you could get rid of some of the redundancy:

```
function changeThemeColor(color) {
    document.getElementById('CSSfile').href = 'css/' + color + '.css';
    switch(color) {
        case "style1":
        default:
            setCookie('ThemeColor','style1',7);
            break;
        case "style2":
            setCookie('ThemeColor','style6',7);
            break;
    }
}
```

The `style2` is sending `'style6'` to `setCookie()`. If that's a mistake, and it should be sending `'style2'`, you could further reduce it.

```
function changeThemeColor(color) {
    document.getElementById('CSSfile').href = 'css/' + color + '.css';
    setCookie('ThemeColor', color, 7);
}
```

Comment: wow  your are god !! ; the minified version of my script is so nice . i will use it . thanks

Comment: except for he writes style6.css for style2 param... hence the switch :)

Comment: @Dimitar - Yep, I noted that in my answer. :o) *"The style2 is sending 'style6' to setCookie(). If that's a mistake, and it should be sending 'style2', you could further reduce it."*

Comment: fair enough, just nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

For MooTools:

```
function changeThemeColor(color)
{
    switch(color)
    {
        case "style1":
        default:
            $('CSSfile').set('href','css/style1.css');
            Cookie.write('ThemeColor','style1',{'duration':7});
            break;
        case "style2":
            $('CSSfile').set('href','css/style2.css');
            Cookie.write('ThemeColor','style6',{'duration':7});
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the edits are so small I wouldn't even bother implementing them if I were you. It's not going to make your site more futureproof either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery change this

```
document.getElementById('CSSfile').href = 'css/style1.css';
```

to

```
$("#CSSfile").attr("href",'css/style1.css');
```

and if you want to change the color from a div is

```
$("#divId").css("color","#f0f0f0")
```

Sorry for my english, i am from Argentina

edit:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie
Here you have a cookie's jQuery plugin

Answer (score 1):

for mootools (or indeed, jquery) i'd create a map of styles instead and do something like this:

```
var changeThemeColor = function(colour) {
    var colours = { // set your mapping here.
        style1: "style1",
        style2: "style6"
    }, style = colours[colour] || colours['style1']; // default to style1 if not mapped

    document.id("CSSfile").set("href", "css/"+style+ ".css");
    Cookie.write("ThemeColor", style, {
        duration: 7,
        path: "/"
    });
};
```

trying to make it more modular/pattern based so it can easily support adding new styles in the future. the best way is to have this via an `options` var as second argument where you can overwrite (externally) the default mapping and internally, do `Object.merge()`.